# Sporadic "Permission Denied" Error When Doing Fast Read/Write-Cycled File IO

Tags: c, file-io

**I basically have the following setup:**

1. Pick a filename
2. Loop exactly `100` times:

   1. Write file
   2. Measure its size (open it, `fseek` end, close it)
3. Write file

After a certain point (the smallest I've measured is 80 loops), the write operation fails with a permission denied error (it can't open the file).  This only happens *sometimes*.  Sometimes the entire thing works as expected.

Now, the only thing I'm aware of that should be able to cause this is that the file pointer is still open by something.  But, I'm certain it's not me.  Like any even remotely competent programmer, I of course *always* close files after opening them.  In particular, as mentioned above, the file is closed after measuring its size, and after writing it.  The first thing I double-checked was this.

Additionally, all file IO functions are checked for validity.  If, for example, the problem were the close failing, I would know.  So *the first file IO call that fails is the* `fopen`.

My question: what's happening?

---

<sup>[Test system: Windows 7, with latest drivers, including for filesystem.]</sup>
<sup>[Context: I've written a PNG compressor.  To get the best compression, you just have to try a bunch of parameters.  As a simple test, I figured I could write the file with each combination, measure its size, and then repeat until I found the best.  I'm currently making it do this in-core, but this little test seemed to produce a weird result.]</sup>

Comment: Sounds like you overwhelmed the file system. Did you check `errno` after the failure? Also, you'd be better off just counting bytes until you find the best parameters, and then write the file once.

Comment: @user3386109 absolutely; that's how I knew it's a "permission denied" error. Interestingly, PNG files don't know how well they're compressing until they're done writing. But indeed, my current version does this process in-core--which is better anyway--sidestepping the problem.